# Trying to display all values of row from dataset when selecting an item in a listbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm trying to be able to click an item in a listbox and be able to view all of the data in it's corresponding row. Wondering what's wrong with my code now?

I have tried multiple times to query the database with the specific selected listbox item. Yet it doesn't convert to a string, it just displays "System.Data.Datarow", and because of that, I can't query successfully. The original Query works, and if the objects fields match the rows, it shows the correct lastname I'm looking for. The problem is more of trying to then click any of the multiple last names in the list box, and having that populate the empty textboxes next to the listbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace College_Dorm_Mate_Matching_App
{
    public partial class Preferences : Form 
    {
        public Preferences()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //create Student list and instance of student object
        List<Student> newStudent = new List<Student>();
        Student myStudent = new Student();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = D:\CCSU\Spring 19\MIS  312\Final Project\College Dorm Mate Matching App\College Dorm Mate Matching App\Students.mdf; Integrated Security = True");

        //add textbox comobox values to student object
        public void AddItemsToObj()
        {
            myStudent.FirstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
            myStudent.LastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
            myStudent.Age = int.Parse(textBoxAge.Text);
            myStudent.Sport = comboBoxSport.Text;
            myStudent.Music = comboBoxMusic.Text;
            myStudent.Hobbies = comboBoxHobbies.Text;
            myStudent.Recharge = comboBoxRecharge.Text;
            myStudent.Vices = comboBoxVices.Text;
            myStudent.Weekend = comboBoxWeekends.Text; 
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddItemsToObj();

            //query db
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From  Students where FavoriteSport='"+ myStudent.Sport +"' AND Hobbies='"+ myStudent.Hobbies +"' AND MusicTaste='" + myStudent.Music+"'" , con);
            //create new table to store
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            //fill new DT
            adapter.Fill(table);
            //add sources into listbox if they match
            listBoxMatches.DataSource = table;
            listBoxMatches.DisplayMember = "LastName";
            listBoxMatches.ValueMember = "FirstName";
        }

        private void listBoxMatches_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Students where LastName='" + listBoxMatches.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                textBoxfnameout.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
                textBoxlnameout.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
                textBoxageout.Text = dr["Age"].ToString();
                textBoxsportout.Text = dr["FavoriteSport"].ToString();
                textBoxmusicout.Text = dr["MusicTaste"].ToString();
                textBoxhobbiesout.Text = dr["Hobbies"].ToString();
                textBoxrechargeout.Text = dr["Recharge"].ToString();
                textBoxweekendout.Text = dr["Weekend"].ToString();
                textBoxcigout.Text = dr["cigs"].ToString();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I would like for the textboxes that are besides the listbox to be populated with corresponding data of selecteditem.

Comment: Please ensure that you read the information for tags so that you don't inadvertently misuse them. The `visual-studio` tag is intended for questions about the Visual Studio application (as opposed to code written using it).